# getProcID and getProcessHandle functions

Tags: c++, c++11, windows, winapi

I made two functions: one to get process id and the other to get a handle with all access to that process using the process id. I'm looking for help with making these easy to use on all types of projects. The only thing I know is maybe letting the person chose the open process properties.

```
DWORD getProcID(const std::wstring &windowName, std::string &status)
{
    DWORD processID = NULL;
    HWND windowHandle = NULL;

    windowHandle = FindWindowW(NULL, windowName.c_str()); // Gets handle to top window (class name, window name)
    if (windowHandle) {
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, &processID); // returns thread that made window (window, process for window)
            if (processID != 0) {
                    return processID;
            }
            else { // if process id is bad 
                status = "Error with process";
                return 0;
            }
    }
    else { // if window name is bad/not there
        status = "Error with window";
        return 0;
    }
    CloseHandle(windowHandle); // close window handle since we dont need it anymore
    return 0;
}

HANDLE &getProcessHandle(const DWORD processID, std::string &status) {
    HANDLE procHandle = NULL;

    if (processID != 0) {
        procHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID); // returns handle to process (what you want, inherit stuff, process id)
        if (procHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE || procHandle != NULL) { // if handle returned by openProcess is good
            status = "Game is ready to hack";
        }
        else { // if handle retured by openProcess is bad
            status = "Error with handle";
        }
    }
    else {
        status = "Error with process id";
    }
    return procHandle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fairly routinely (not so much here as at work, for example) kind of "scold" people for creating classes where they really only need or want a single function.

This, however, is kind of the opposite case: functions where you really want classes. In particular, RAII can provide a real benefit here, and for that you need a class with a dtor.

I'm not excited about the situation with reporting errors by putting them into a string (and hoping that an empty string indicates success). I'd rather follow the model of "succeed or throw".

To keep that simple, I think it can also benefit from defining an `assure` (or something on that order) that's at least roughly similar to `assert`, except that it remains intact in release builds, and (perhaps) throws an exception instead of just aborting if a problem is seen. For example:

```
#define assure(cond, msg) do { if (!(cond)) throw std::runtime_error(msg); } while (0)
```

With that in hand, I'd probably start with a WindowHandle type something like this:

```
class WindowHandle {
    HWND handle;
public:
    WindowHandle(std::wstring const &windowName) 
        : handle(FindWindowW(nullptr, windowName.c_str())) 
    { 
        assure(handle != 0, "Window not found");
    }
    operator HWND() { return handle; }
};
```

Note that (at least as far as I know, or MSDN seems to indicate) you normally *don't* want to call `CloseHandle` on the handle returned from FindWindow. If you did want to, you'd do that in the destructor.

Likewise, a process ID would look something like this:

```
class ProcId {
    WindowHandle handle;
    DWORD id;
public:
    ProcId(std::wstring const &window_name) 
        : handle(window_name)
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, &id);
        assure(id != 0, "Error retrieving process ID");
    }
    operator DWORD() { return id; }
};
```

Finally, we get to the process handle (where we finally *do* need to use `Closehandle`):

```
class procHandle {
    ProcId id;
    HANDLE handle;
public:
    procHandle(std::wstring const &name, DWORD access = PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS)
        : id(name), 
        handle(OpenProcess(access, FALSE, id)   )
    {
        // according to MSDN, returns NULL in case of error
        assure(handle != NULL, "Error retrieving process handle");
    }

    ~procHandle() { CloseHandle(handle); }

    operator HANDLE() { return handle; }
};
```

Note how each of these builds on the previous, so each only does one thing (i.e., we're following the single responsibility principle). Also note how the code to open a process handle becomes completely trivial:

```
procHandle p(L"SomeWindowName");
```

If we add in code to print out the error message if something goes wrong, it's still only marginally more complex:

```
try {
    procHandle p(L"Start");
    // Code to use process handle goes here.
} // handle will be closed automatically when we exit the scope
catch (std::exception const &e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
}
```

At least to me, this seems both easier to understand, and easier to use (and harder to use incorrectly).